# Led Strip light flashing

Tags: led

**strong text**Does anyone know what kind of led driver i need for this strip ?? its not started flashing

https://ibb.co/prTq90P

Comment: My! That **is** strong text!

Comment: @MarkRich, i bet that you did not even read what you posted ... flashing or not flashing, which is it? ... why should anyone put more effort into an answer, than the effort that you put into the question